# Flash 8 ActionScript - Movie Clip location

Tags: flash, actionscript, drag-and-drop, movieclip

In Flash 8 I've created a movieclip. Inside I've added 3 more symbols (movieclips). 1 box and two images, goal is to drag and drop the rigt image in the box.  how do I do it?

```
on(press) {
startDrag("_root.FirstMC.RObject");
}

on(release) {
stopDrag();
if (_root.FirstMC.RObject._droptarget == "/Box") {
    gotoAndStop(3);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can drag and drop, but it does not recognize dropping location (does not go to frame 3). Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hitTest, e.g.

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame){
    if (yourMC.hitTest(yourImage))
    {
        what is supposed to happen here...

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.